# React-Native: AsyncStorage crashes Android app

Tags: android, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm writing an App for Android and iOS using react-native.
The iOS version works perfectly but the Android version crashes every time it try to calls a `AsyncStorage` function.

When my App launches, it checks if there are some user-information stored on the device. It uses this function here:

```
static async getActiveUser() {
    return null;
    try {
      let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@UserStore:activeUser');
      if (value !== null){
        return JSON.parse(value);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

As I said before, the iOS version runs perfectly. When I run this code on Android, it crashes at this line:

```
let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@UserStore:activeUser');
```

The function `getActiveUser()` gets called inside the `componentDidMount` function.

I'm searching for hours on a solution!! Can someone help? Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

Error-Log:

```
07-16 13:16:49.082 7154-7205/com.mblum.cvjm E/unknown:ViewManager: Error while updating prop color
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getInt(ReadableNativeMap.java:159)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactStylesDiffMap.getInt(ReactStylesDiffMap.java:68)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$BoxedIntPropSetter.extractProperty(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:275)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:101)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:154)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:58)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:298)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:289)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:364)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
07-16 13:16:49.085 7154-7205/com.mblum.cvjm E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'color' in shadow node of type: AndroidTextInput
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:113)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:154)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:58)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:298)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:289)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:364)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getInt(ReadableNativeMap.java:159)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactStylesDiffMap.getInt(ReactStylesDiffMap.java:68)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$BoxedIntPropSetter.extractProperty(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:275)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:101)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:154) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:58) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:298) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:289) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:364) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
07-16 13:16:49.098 7154-7205/com.mblum.cvjm E/unknown:ViewManager: Error while updating prop color
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getInt(ReadableNativeMap.java:159)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactStylesDiffMap.getInt(ReactStylesDiffMap.java:68)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$BoxedIntPropSetter.extractProperty(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:275)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:101)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:154)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:58)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:298)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:289)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:364)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
07-16 13:16:49.110 7154-7205/com.mblum.cvjm E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'color' in shadow node of type: AndroidTextInput
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:113)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:154)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:58)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:298)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:289)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:364)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getInt(ReadableNativeMap.java:159)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactStylesDiffMap.getInt(ReactStylesDiffMap.java:68)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$BoxedIntPropSetter.extractProperty(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:275)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:101)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:154) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:58) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:298) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:289) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:364) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
07-16 13:16:49.205 7154-7154/com.mblum.cvjm D/ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.destroy() start
    CatalystInstanceImpl.destroy() start
07-16 13:16:49.220 7154-7154/com.mblum.cvjm W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager
07-16 13:16:49.241 7154-7154/com.mblum.cvjm W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager
07-16 13:16:49.262 7154-7184/com.mblum.cvjm W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure /dev/null/Android/data/com.mblum.cvjm/cache: 400
07-16 13:16:49.276 7154-7154/com.mblum.cvjm D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-16 13:16:49.278 7154-7154/com.mblum.cvjm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mblum.cvjm, PID: 7154
    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: Trying to add unknown view tag: 20
     detail: View tag:32
      children(4): [
    10,13,16,18,
     ],
      viewsToAdd(1): [
    [4,20],
     ],

        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.handleException(ReactContext.java:313)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:33)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:136)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:107)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:909)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:655)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: Trying to add unknown view tag: 20
     detail: View tag:32
      children(4): [
    10,13,16,18,
     ],
      viewsToAdd(1): [
    [4,20],
     ],

        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.manageChildren(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:394)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$ManageChildrenOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:180)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run(UIViewOperationQueue.java:822)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.flushPendingBatches(UIViewOperationQueue.java:929)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.access$2100(UIViewOperationQueue.java:47)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:989)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:31)
            ... 13 more
```

Comment: There must be some crash logs. can you show error logs?

Comment: @Khemraj how to enable these on android?

Comment: You can see crash on node server command. or in command where you start server by npm start or run-android.

Comment: @Khemraj - no I do not. I'm trying to find the logs - I add them to my post ASAP

Comment: hi Mike_NotGuilty, hope you have android studio then share log from it.  in LogCat.

Comment: see my edit.. finally worked

Comment: Do you have an input field in your app? Seems like you are updating a color prop that makes the app crash. Not the AsyncStorage.

Comment: Wow... that was... simple?! - When I debugged the app, it always crashed at this line. The code after this line did not execute. But it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

your log,

`07-16 13:16:49.098 7154-7205/com.mblum.cvjm E/unknown:ViewManager: Error while updating prop color`
It is not a problem in your `AsyncStorage` as the log clearly states that.

some tips:

If you ever think AsyncStorage is not responding well, it usually means you have a wrong data type in there. So always try `AsyncStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify('token'));`
(just for debugging purposes)

Comment: I have installed package "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1", and app is crashing ,